# cin.get with logical operator in while loop

Tags: c++, while-loop

This program in C++ is very simple:

```
while (ch = cin.get())
 cout << ch;
```

If I put a character and then I press the Enter, I'll see this sign on the screen. For example:

```
w
w
k
k
```

I can change the code to the following form:

```
ch = cin.get();
 while (ch != 'q')
 {
  cout << ch;
  ch = cin.get();
 }
```

In this case the program will stop if I put the q letter. I tried to make a much shorter version of last program:

```
while (ch = cin.get() && ch != 'q')
 cout << ch;
```

Unfortunately this program doesn't print any character. If I put the letter and press the Enter, the cursor indicates new line on the screen (without printing) and the program waits for a new character. I don't understand why in this program the method "cin.get()" doesn't assign any character to the "ch" variable. Of course the type of ch is char.

Comment: Try `while (ch = cin.get(), ch != 'q')` instead of `while (ch = cin.get() && ch != 'q')`

Comment: @πάντα ῥεῖ  if input is exhausted before `q` is entered, your `while (ch = cin.get(), ch != 'q')` will spin printing garbage forever.

Comment: @TonyD OK, `while (ch = cin.get(), cin && ch != 'q')` then :) ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you look at [C++'s operator precedence](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_precedence) you'll see that `&&` binds more strongly than `=`, which basically means your code is evaluated as...

```
while (ch = (cin.get() && ch != 'q'))
```

...not...

```
while ((ch = cin.get()) && ch != 'q')
```

You should add `(` and `)` as in the last line above.

What's actually been happening is that `ch = cin.get() && ch != 'q'` tests that it can get a character (likely `true`), and that the character is not `q` (`true` if the character doesn't just happen to have a `q` on the first `while` loop iteration when you read it seemingly uninitialised - which would be Undefined Behaviour - though perhaps you give it an initial value when you define it).  `true && true` is `true`, so it's equivalent to `ch = true`.  `true` is converted to `char` with ASCII value `1`... your terminal might print something for that or not... it's not one of the normal "printable" (visible) ASCII codes.  On the next loop iteration we know `ch` is `1` so it can never compare equal to `q`... the only way to terminate now is if `cin.get()` fails due to an "end of file" condition - pressing control-D on UNIX/Linux or control-Z on Windows, or something that breaks the whole program out of the loop like control-C or a kill/end task.